# Localstorage doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm adding signup and signin into my React.js application but I can't understand why if I signin and then inspect my browser console (application tab) I don't see any items in the localstorage.

Here the relavant parts of my code:

inside signin.js **component**: (when I click the submit button on the signin form I trigger this function)

```
handleFormSubmit({ email, password }) {
        this.props.signinUser({ email, password });
}
```

My **action**:

```
export function signinUser({ email, password }) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/users/signin', { email, password }).then(response => {
        if (response.data.username){
          dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER, payload:response.data }); // If request is good update state to indicate user is authenticated
          localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token); // - Save the JWT token
          browserHistory.push('/');
        }
      }).catch(() => {dispatch(authError('Bad Login Info'));});
  }
}
```

Do I have to import LocalStorage somewhere in my application?

Comment: What is your `response.data.username` returning. Also, why is `response.data.token` in a string?

Comment: as an aside, you should probably use `sessionStorage` for this

Comment: @Mr.Alien response.data.username is returning the username (from a mongodb database) of the user as soon as he clicks the submit button. I tried with both response.data.token and "response.data.token" but both seem to not be saved to localstorage

Comment: In your code can you try to log `localStorage.getItem('token')` and see if you get a result . Also Try , `localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(response.data.token));`

Comment: it seems that response.data.token is undefined. I tried to add an hardcoded value to the localstorage but it still doesn't store it. I tried this: var myToken = [{token:"token here"}]; and then localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(myToken));

Comment: When I run it in a snippet localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(mytoken)) and then extract like JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'))[0].token works

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yes it works, but if I inspect chrome console I don't see anything under localstorage tab. I'd expect to see 'token'. This is what I can't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say that you `response.data.token` is undefined and so it won't be able to store in the localStorage.

However for your use case

```
myToken = [{token:"token here"}]
localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(myToken));
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'))[0].token);
```

works

To see that in the developer console

Press F12  and then in the Applications tab, on the left menu expand localstorage to see your domain and then click on that, you should be able to see your localstorage item, otherwise you won't be able to get it via `getItem`.

[image]